# Is there an equivalent to Adobe Creative Suite?

Tags: software-recommendation

Adobe has the creative suite - are there any alternatives for Ubuntu?

Comment: Side note: feature request form: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform&PID=4172469 Lots of people used it to ask Adobe for a Linux CS.

Comment: Heh, Done that a while ago @Rinzwind

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't such thing as a "Creative Suite". What you have instead are several alternatives to the different programs in Adobe's suite:

- Gimp vs Photoshop
- Inkscape vs Illustrator
- Scribus vs InDesign
- Tons of editors and IDE's (such as Netbeans, Eclipse or Bluefish; or Kompozer, which is a WYSIWYG HTML editor, or Bluegriffon which is its rewritten although harder to use version) instead of DreamWeaver
- etc

Those programs might fulfill your needs individually. The thing that they miss, though, is the great integration between Adobe's suite products (same icons, same GUI, easy to share things between them and so on).

Answer (score 10):

There is [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/) which is an Ubuntu derivative that is made for artists.

It comes pre-installed with the following [graphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/Graphics) tools:

- The GIMP
- Inkscape
- Blender
- Synfig Studio

And a bunch of other tools.

It is kinda like a creative suite as an OS.

Answer (score 5):

If the linux equivalents like gimp, inkscape and scribus fail to meet your needs, why not install the latest version of WINE and run Adobe's own suite on your linux/ubuntu setup, but be warned things may get buggy although I have been running Photoshop without any problems for a while... Go here:

http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

That is really a pity that Adobe didn't create the version for Linux.
However I used Inkscape, Gimp and Scribus for my hobby graphics. But finally when I bought Adobe Creative Suite I don't want to go back. The truth is that Inkscape, Gimp and Scribus are superb, but CS is much beyond them. However I am sure that regardless if You master Inkscape, Gimp and Scribus or CS5 You can make astonishing stuff.

I have heard that [Xara Xtreme](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/) is comparable to Illustrator and for now it is the best vector graphics soft for Linux. It did impress me, and I would reccomend it.

Answer (score 0):

Gimp is a little alternative to Photoshop but photoshop is so much more powerful than Gimp.
InkSpace is a good free/open source application comparable with Illustrator.
ZendStudio is a good commercial IDE for php. Other IDE supports more language.

Linux will have a better position if there is a Adobe Creative Suite like suite.

Answer (score -1):

I have an Imac with **Adobe CS3**, which I was considering to upgrade except for the cost. I rather spend the money on a new computer with more RAM.

I have opted to try **Corel Draw Creative Suite 6**. I picked it up for 50 bucks on Ebay, the only catch is it only runs on Windows which I can run on a virtual program. I haven't tried it yet because I'm waiting for the new computer with more RAM. That's something you may want to consider.

I'm pretty sure you can run a virtual program with your operating system. Read up on the system requirement for whatever virtual program you use. There is a free one called virtual box, but I don't know how good it is.

Answer (score -1):

For an alternative to Acrobat, try PDF Studio:

http://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/